# Removing low frequency (hiss) noise from video in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avfoundation, audio-recording

I am recording videos and playing them back using `AVFoundation`. Everything is perfect except the hissing which is there in the whole video. You can hear this hissing in every video captured from any iPad. Even videos captured from Apple's inbuilt camera app has it.

To hear it clearly, you can record a video in a place as quiet as possible without speaking anything. It can be very easily detected through headphones and keeping volume to maximum.

After researching, I found out that this hissing is made by preamplifier of the device and cannot be avoided while recording.

Only possible solution is to remove it during post processing of audio. Low frequency noise can be removed by implementing low pass filter and noise gates. There are applications and software like **Adobe Audition** which can perform this operation. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lIjFBG6w58) shows how it is achieved using Adobe Audition.

I have searched Apple docs and found nothing which can achieve this directly. So I want to know if there exists any library, api or open source project which can perform this operation. If not, then how can I start going in right direction because it does looks like a complex task.

Comment: There's a nice pod called NVDSP that'll handle what you need https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP just look for the low pass filter class also all the files that use NSDSP have to be Objective C++

Comment: Another common approach is to use compression.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner : Can you elaborate a bit on that approach? How to go about it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_gate However, I got a bit mixed up in the terminology. Compression and gating are similar but also kind of opposite.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Yeah.. So any idea how to implement noise gate?

Comment: @blancos -- Sorry! I'm more of a Java guy, and even there am not up on all the sound libraries. I tend to write my own implementations of things when possible. But I thought that if you had the term and concept, you could further hone your search. The basic concept, to implement, requires that you monitor the amplitude of the wave data (I think there are some RMS-based algos for this), and when ever the amplitude drops below a threshold, drop it to zero via some sort of ramp. Of course, if a library can be found, that could save some time.